# inheriting the Public User View (ODOO 12)

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-12

I'm working on odoo 12 and I want to inherit the public user homepage because I want a specific view to appear once he logs in.

I have this error every time (public user). I tried this code but it's not working:

```
<odoo>
    <template id="theme_custom.new_homepage" inherit_id="website.homepage">
        <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrap']" position="replace">
          <div id="wrap" class="oe_structure">
              hello
          </div>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

[image]

Can anyone help?